# Does the amount of html on page affect speed?

Tags: html

Of course the amount of HTML loaded ***all at once*** will affect speed. But will the overall amount of HTML on a website page affect performance speed?
If so, by how much? Will roughly 1,000 list items make a noticeable difference?

e.g.

I have a website that loads HTML per request and removes the previously loaded HTML. The user will sometimes go back and forth, which requires loading each time. Instead of reloading it each time, I'd like to just hide the loaded HTML and reshow it when they request it again.

[Here's a link to an example on my website](https://flashkase.com/library/?userid=1002)

Edit: For those that want to close this, this question falls under this topic.

```
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the amount of HTML effects page speed.
That's why many developers today are minifying their HTML as a part of the build process.

BUT, you better ask yourself not HOW MUCH HTML do you load, but WHAT KIND of HTML are you going to load.

for example: if you have 200 paragraph elements with lots of text it will be just fine. but what if you have 100 big IMG elements? in that case, maybe hiding them (but still loading them) is not such a good idea and its better to load them on demand.